# Automorphism group of elliptic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I am reading Vakil's Algebraic geometry. There is exercise:

> Suppose $(\mathrm{E},\mathrm{p})$ is an elliptic curve over an algebraically closed
>   field $k$ of characteristic not $2$ or $3$. Show that the automorphism group of $(\mathrm{E},\mathrm{p})$ 
>   is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, $\mathbb{Z}/4$, or $\mathbb{Z}/6$.

However, I think it is not correct. I know that the order automprphism group order could be $2,4$ or $6$. But I think it should be isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$, and $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/3$. Am I right? Also I think when char  $k=3$, it could be isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/3$, is it right? Last question, if char $k=2$, how could we get the automprphism group? Since only when char $k\not=2$, we could get the group in term of one fix point $\infty$, and three other point on $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. I have no idea how to compute the group when char $k=2$. More generally, in the theory of elliptic curves, we always need to assume char $k\not =2$, but what should we do if char $k=2$?

Comment: Vakil's assertion is correct, but the automorphism group can be $\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/3$. That's because that group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/6$.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I make a stupid mistake. But I still do not know why the order 4 group should be $\mathbb{Z}/4$. The order 4 group comes from the order 2 permutation and the interchanging of two sheets of the curve (since it is the double  cover). It seems that they are both order two elements and hence the group should be isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$

Answer (score 5):

In the case that the base field is not of characteristic $2$ or $3$, the curve can be put in the form $$ y^2 = x^3+Ax+B$$ and the automorphisms are of the form $x=u^2x'$ and $y=u^3y'$ where $u^{4}A=A$ and $u^{6}B=B$. If $AB\neq 0$, then $u^{2}=1$ and the group is cyclic of degree 2. If $AB=0$, then either $B=0$ and $u^4=1$ or $A=0$ and $u^6=1$, and in this case there's a natural cyclic group structure on the solutions. (Further, $\Bbb Z/2\times \Bbb Z/3\cong \Bbb Z/6$, so there's no disagreement with that specific part of your idea.)

For characteristics $2,3$, the general idea is that you have to be a little more careful about things. Here, that means how you put the curve in to a canonical form like in the first paragraph, but it can still be done. See for instance appendix A in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, where automorphism groups are explained for curves in characteristic $2$ and $3$. In short, the group in characteristic 3 can be of order $12$ and the group in characteristic $2$ can be of order $24$. If you go look at the calculations, you should be able to tell whether they're cyclic or not.

Comment: Oh, I know. Thank you very much! But I try to figure out the automorphisms using the fact that elliptic curves are hyperelliptic when $k\not =2.$ The automorphims of elliptic curves corresponds with one fix point named $\infty$ and permutation of three other points.

Comment: For example, the order 4 group comes from the order 2 permutation and the interchanging of two sheets of the curve (since it is the double cover). It seems that they are both order two elements and hence the group should be isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$. Where I made a mistake?

Comment: @Mike Perhaps your two order $2$ elements are the same?

Comment: If you're hoping for a particular method of solution, you should specify this in the problem statement so answerers know what to aim for. Anyways, as Lord Shark says, you have to show that these are two distinct elements to conclude this group is $\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/2$. The evidence in the above post shows that this is not the case.

Comment: Ok, I think I probably know where I make a mistake.